# Tutorial on Compass Docs

Tags: compass-sass

The Compass [docs](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/) are really confusing to me. I need a tutorial on how to read them.  Does anyone know of a good one out there?  When Google for help, I just get a bunch of slightly related stackoverflow.com and compass-lang.com results which all assume I understand how to read the cryptic Compass docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't really find any Compass tutorial as it's neither a language nor a framework nor any of that. It's just a toolkit, you go and search for stuff in it and keep what you judge useful.
The help section do offer additional help on biffer features of Compass like [spriting](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/) but apart from that, there is no better tutorial than just going through the categories and look at what you think looks awesome.

Comment: Not really what I was looking for, but I guess it's better than no answer.  I understand how to use Compass, but it's just the finer points that can only be found in the documentation that I don't understand, because the documentation itself is so cryptic to me.